# Pause and Continue Variable Incrementing

Tags: javascript, variables, codepen

I need to pause the var i from incrementing when it reaches 25, and continue incrementing when the Submit button is pressed. Sorry for the messy coding.
And would there be an easier way to insert line breaks?
Thanks for taking time out of the day to help.

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/xderpyxcreeperx/pen/vYEdwXJ?editors=1111)

```js
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('num'),
  resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset'),
  nameTxt = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
  nameSubmit = document.getElementById('submit')
var i = 0
var text = "Hello. What is your name?"
var breaks = [6]
var name = ""

setInterval(function(){
 if (breaks.includes(i) == true){
  p[0].innerHTML += "<br>"
 } else {
 p[0].innerHTML += text.charAt(i)
 }
 i++
 if (i == 25){
  nameTxt.style.visibility = "visible"
  nameSubmit.style.visibility = "visible"
 }
},100)

resetBtn.onclick = function(){
 i = 0
 p[0].innerHTML = ""
}
nameTxt.style.visibility = "hidden"
nameSubmit.style.visibility = "hidden"

nameSubmit.onclick = function(){
 name = nameTxt.value
 nameTxt.style.visibility = "hidden"
 nameSubmit.style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P);

body{
   font-family: 'Press Start 2P',serif;
 background: black;
 color: limegreen
}
button{
 width: 100px;
 height: 25px;
 font-family: 'Press Start 2P',serif;
 background: black;
 color: limegreen;
 border-color: limegreen;
 cursor: pointer
}
input{
 width: 100px;
 height: 25px;
 font-family: 'Press Start 2P',serif;
 background: black;
 color: limegreen;
 border-color: limegreen;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<text class="num"></text>
<input><button id="submit">Submit</button>
<br>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('num'),
        resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset'),
        nameTxt = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
        nameSubmit = document.getElementById('submit')
var i = 0
var text = "Hello. What is your name?"
var breaks = [6]
var name = ""
var btnClicked = false;

setInterval(function(){
    if (breaks.includes(i) == true){
        p[0].innerHTML += "<br>"
    } else {
    p[0].innerHTML += text.charAt(i)
    }
    if (btnClicked || i < 25) i++;
    if (i == 25){
        nameTxt.style.visibility = "visible"
        nameSubmit.style.visibility = "visible"
    }
},100)

resetBtn.onclick = function(){
    i = 0
    p[0].innerHTML = ""
}
nameTxt.style.visibility = "hidden"
nameSubmit.style.visibility = "hidden"

nameSubmit.onclick = function(){
        btnClicked = true;
    name = nameTxt.value
    nameTxt.style.visibility = "hidden"
    nameSubmit.style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```